# "On Lisp": `(a b c) vs '(a b c) vs (list 'a 'b 'c)

Tags: common-lisp, on-lisp

In *On Lisp* (p. 84) Graham says

> `‘(a b c)` (without comma) is equal to `’(a b c)`

and then says

> A backquoted list is equivalent to a call to list with the elements
>   quoted.
> That is, `‘(a b c)` (without comma) is equal to `(list ’a ’b ’c)`.

One statement has to be false since `'(a b c)` and `(list 'a 'b 'c)` don't seem to be equal. The latter is a freshly consed list (safe to modify) while the former is a constant -- or at least the spec allows the compiler to treat it as such.

So maybe it's a very nitpicky question but is a backquoted list (without comma) like `‘(a b c)` equal to `'(a b c)` or equal to `(list 'a 'b 'c)`?

Comment: The list produced by backquote is allowed to share structure with the template itself, so it's not safe to mutate. How it actually works is up to the implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Equal** and **Equivalent** are not the same.

Certainly `(equal '(a b c) (list 'a 'b 'c))` returns `t`, but, as you correctly note yourself, `'(a b c)` is a quoted constant while `(list 'a 'b 'c)` is freshly allocated.

Comment: Ah, ok, so Graham says they are all equal with regard to the relational operator `equal` which I confused with equivalence.